# ShareLinkTask Message Attribute for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using ShareLinkTask in my app as follows:

```
ShareLinkTask myShareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask()
{
   Title = "Title",
   LinkUri = new Uri("https://www.stackoverflow.com/", UriKind.Absolute),
   Message = "Message"
};
myShareLinkTask.Show();
```

It runs fine, but where is the Message supposed to be visible to recipients? When I try it out I never see it in email, text message, or Facebook. I only ever see the Title and the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the receiving app to decide what to do with the properties you set.